# Reading the result of LINQ and XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to parse a visual studio resource file that contains various translated strings like so:

```
<data name="InvalidGroupType" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>La sélection du type de groupe n'est pas valide.</value>
</data>
<data name="ProgressFailure" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Liste des échecs</value>
</data>
<data name="Loronix" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Loronix</value>
</data>
<data name="InputString" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Entrée</value>
</data>
```

As well as other stuff.  I just want the **data name** and **value** strings.

I tried to parse this file line by line using the following:

```
StreamReader fileMain = new StreamReader(MainFile);
while ((line = fileMain.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string data = checkForData(line); --checks each line for "<data name="
    if( data.Length > 0)
       StringsToTranslatelist.Add(data);
}
```

But I guessed there must be a better way to do this. So I used a LINQ like so:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(resxFile);

var result = from item in xDoc.Descendants("data")
select new
{
    Name = item.Attribute("name").Value,
    Value = item.Element("value").Value
};

foreach (var entry in result)
{
    string name = entry.Name;
    string value = entry.Value;
    //Do somethign here
}
```

THe problem is that when I get to my foreach loop I get an exception or:
**"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyProgram.exe.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object"**

Does anyone know why?? Am I using the LINQ correctly

Comment: What line does it highlight?

Comment: I'm guessing either item.Attribute("name").Value or item.Element("value").Value

Comment: It doesnt highlight any line. It gets past the LINQ statement and then when the dubugger tried to do the first foreach loop the debugger appears to jump back to the select new statement and then I get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some `data` element do not have `name` attribute or `value` element. To avoid this - use casting instead of accessing `Value` property. Otherwise you will receive `NullReferenceException` if either `name` attribute or `value` element is not found

```
var result = from item in xDoc.Descendants("data")
             select new {
                 Name = (string)item.Attribute("name"),
                 Value = (string)item.Element("value")
             };
```

Another possible reason is namespace issue. But default resource files do no have namespaces defined.

Comment: I have changed it to this and its no longer crashing.  But it is returning 'null' for all the 'entry.value' entries.  FOr example: My resource file has <data name="InvalidGroupType" and a corresponding <value>La sélection du type de groupe</value> but the value is being returned as null.

Comment: @HarryBoy just verified - works fine on default resource file. Do you have some namespace defined in your xml file?

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to change item.Attribute("value").Value to item.Element("value").  It now works thanks :)

Comment: @HarryBoy yep, that was an issue - Linq was not able to find `value` attribute, and `item.Attribute("value")` returned `null`